# Firebase permission denied with security rules

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the JSON from my data base in Firebase and I want to do some rules like the auth but I get an error and I don't know what to do:

```
"users" : {
    "0BuRcGEZQRUaQ5T2gQf4RDUcuZE2" : {
      "address" : "La Prensa",
      "email" : "ougishura_5421@hotmail.com",
      "id" : "0BuRcGEZQRUaQ5T2gQf4RDUcuZE2",
      "lastName" : "Vega",
      "middleName" : "Paul",
      "name" : "Christian",
      "nroDocument" : "171645220",
      "phoneNumber" : "1234567890",
      "rol" : "administrador",
      "secondLastName" : "Niama"
    }
}
```

These are the rules that I'm using:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$user_id": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

error:

> angular.js:13550 Error: permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

This is the error that I get in my web app. I can't see the users that I have registered. But when I stop using `$user_id` it works. I think that variable doesn't get my value.

code:

```
resultUsers : function () { 
    var ref = pharmacyFactory.ref.child("users"); 
    var result = $firebaseArray(ref); 
    return result; 
},
```

Comment: There is nothing in your question that reads or writes data, so nothing that can raise a permission denied error. Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the error, it will be hard to answer.

Comment: angular.js:13550 Error: permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. 
This is the error that i get in my web app i cant see the users that i have registered but when i stop using $user_id it works i think that variable doesn't get my value

Comment: @StevenSparkies Please add the code that you are using to retrieve the users data.

Comment: @adolfosrs 

        resultUsers : function () {
          var ref = pharmacyFactory.ref.child("users");
          var result = $firebaseArray(ref);
          return result;
        },

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$firebaseArray(ref)` to keep track of the whole `/users` branch but you are placing your read rules inside `/users/user_id`. **Therefore, since you don't have a read rule in `/users` it will set the default that is `false`.**

If you want users to have read access to the whole `/users` branch but write only to his own user data you might be interested in doing the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        "$user_id": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

If you want the user to only see his own user then you should be using `$firebaseObject(ref.child(userId))` instead of `$firebaseArray`. And working with your rules like the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$user_id": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfect.... but what can i do if i just want that a user just see his own user not the others